# What is the order AWS S3 lists files in a directory?

Tags: amazon-web-services, file, amazon-s3

Does AWS S3 have any order when listing objects? I see there is a restriction of listing 1000 files per API request. In what order will it list those 1000 files? In timestamp or alphabetical order?

I think the API used to list the files is ListObjects.

Comment: Bucket listings are always in alphabetical (or perhaps [Lexicographic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order)) order. Please note that the `Key` includes the **full path**, so the order includes the directory names.

Comment: Thank you @JohnRotenstein. in the listobject API(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjects.html)  , i see that listing is as per alphabetical order. What about reading ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean by "what about reading?"